# Can't locate object method "new" via package "IO::Socket::SSL"

Tags: perl, perl-module

Can anybody throw me a bone on this one?

`Can't locate object method "new" via package "IO::Socket::SSL" at Services/IMAP/Client.pm line 136.`

```
          if ( $use_ssl ) {
135             require IO::Socket::SSL;
136             $imap = IO::Socket::SSL->new (
137                                 Proto    => "tcp",
138                                 PeerAddr => $hostname,
139                                 PeerPort => $port,
140                                 Timeout  => $timeout,
141                                 Domain   => AF_INET,
142                     )
143                     or $self->log_(0, "IO::Socket::SSL error: $@");
144         }
```

It has been running fine for months, but after some upgrading; presumably perl, it started.

Perl version is: (v5.16.3) on RHEL5

```
$perldoc -lm IO::Socket::SSL 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/IO/Socket/SSL.pm 

$perldoc -lm IO::Socket::INET 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/i686-linux/IO/Socket/INET.pm 

$perldoc -lm Net::SSLeay 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/i686-linux/Net/SSLeay.pm
```

Am I missing dependencies?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 These all return without errors.
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e1
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::IP -e1
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::INET6 -e1
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e1
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MNet::SSLeay -e1
[root@gw1 ]#
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using "require" instead of "use"?

Comment: Hi, no reason. I didn't write this piece of code. I'll test it. Thanks!

Comment: With use instead of require same thing 

Can't locate object method "new" via package "IO::Socket::SSL" at Services/IMAP/Client.pm line 137"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit embarrassing, but I found the issue causing my problems:
The shebang in the files used were:
`#!/usr/bin/perl` (Using the vendor perl)
Whereas
`#!/bin/env/ perl`
or
`#!/usr/bin/local/perl`
Is needed for my non vendor perl installed version.
Adjust for platform.

To everybody who provided input, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`IO::Socket::SSL` will try to load other modules before it decides from which module to inherit. These are:

- `IO::Socket::IP`
- `IO::Socket::INET6`
- `IO::Socket::INET`

Since you do have `IO::Socket::INET` installed, maybe one of the other two modules is making trouble?

Comment: Thanks,


I have IO::Socket::IP


perldoc -lm IO::Socket::IP

/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/IO/Socket/IP.pm

Installed IO::Socket::INET6

perldoc -lm IO::Socket::INET6

/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/IO/Socket/INET6.pm


Still giving me the same issue.

Comment: These all return without errors.  
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -e1  
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::IP -e1  
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::INET6 -e1    
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e1  
[root@gw1 ]# perl -MNet::SSLeay -e1  
[root@gw1 ]#

Comment: How does one add a linebreak in these comments? Two spaces is not working for me!